# Integrating sessions from osCommerce store to main site

Tags: php, session, oscommerce

I am in the process of integrating user logins with my existing site to an osCommerce shopping cart. The problem is osCommerce stores the sessions in a database and my existing website does not.

I can't get the global login to work. That is, I have to login into the shopping cart separately to use it. I don't want to change the existing login system used by osCommerce but have to copy the session data to the shopping cart somehow so that I can login in from one place and do shopping.

For example, when a user logs in from www.example.com/login.php I register a session variable called `$_SESSION['auth.user.id']`.

When I use `www.example.com/shopping/shopping_cart.php` I need to use the same `$_SESSION['auth.user.id']` but in the style of osCommerce. If I use `session_start()` on top of the `shopping_cart.php` page before application_top.php I can access the session but the problem is shopping cart specific session details are lost.

If I use `session_start()` after `application_top.php`, `$_SESSION['auth.user.id']` is lost.

How do I get around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are initializing wrong session variables. Take a look at login.php of OCS:

```
    tep_session_register('customer_id');
    tep_session_register('customer_default_address_id');
    tep_session_register('customer_first_name');
    tep_session_register('customer_country_id');
    tep_session_register('customer_zone_id');
    tep_session_unregister('noaccount');
```